# How to format currency from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, string-formatting, currency

### The goal

I want to format correctly the currency from database.

### The problem

I'm formatting the currency from database with this:

```
@String.Format("{0:C}", @Model["MinProductPrice"])
```

The problem is: `150` have to be `1,50`, and not `150,00` — and this formatting is doing this.

**What is the right formatting type to my case?**

Comment: That's because 150 is a integer value. Formating with `0:C` is considering the 150 is the integer part of your number. In this case, you could think in split the string, but it is not nice to do.

Comment: Is the actual value in the database 150? Are you assuming that the last two digits in the values stored value in the column are always following a decimal/comma? There are other column types that will store doubles, floats, currency etc depending on the database you're using.

Comment: @chiefGui, if at all possible I would heavily consider changing the column type to money (if you're using SQL server) or something equivalent that handles decimals. This is a bug waiting to happen. You should always represent your data with the correct column types when possible. Otherwise, other developers will grab it out of the database as is and assume that no calculation is needed.

Comment: @jlafay Hello! I'm using MySQL, and "int" isn't the best data type to work with because of its performance? Thanks about the guide.

Comment: @jlafay I have changed to DECIMAL(10,2) — what you think about this?

Comment: in sql there a type name money. You should use that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I attributed the casting responsibility to database. I'm using MySQL and the query is like this:

```
ROUND(CAST(MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`) AS DECIMAL)/100,2) as `minProductPrice`
```

Anyway, I would to thanks [jlafay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179386/jlafay) and [csharpler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652345/csharpler) about their answers — they were very helpful and worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to divide the number by 100 first (remember to change the type), so `150` becomes `1.50`, which gets converted to `"1,50"` depending on locale:

```
@String.Format("{0:C}", @Model["MinProductPrice"] / 100.0m)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll extend my comments into an answer, I think that's more appropriate. I think you should change the column type to a money or decimal type to prevent bugs by making the use of the column more obvious. Your output on your page will be correct and won't require any "magic numbers" to get it to print out properly.

Just a note but you can also print a currency string doing this:

```
@Model["MinProductPrice"].ToString("C")
```